# Rails - HTTParty request through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, httparty

I am new to both Rails and AJAX.
I want to consume an API which is hosted on a different website.  I ran into problems with cross origin HTTP request.  So I tried doing this by using HTTParty.

In the code below, I am setting the text of $(".result") as JSON.parse(HTTParty()) request, so that it can query the website and give me the result.

*Rails code:*

```
<%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_field :content, class: 'ajax-control' %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<p class="result"></p>
```

*Javascript code:*

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.ajax-control').on('keyup',function(){
       var charCount = $(this).val().length;
       if(charCount===3){
        var str1='<%=JSON.parse(HTTParty.get("http://example.com/api.php?param='+$(this).val()+'"))%>'
        $(".result").text(str1);
       }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now comes the weird problem.  The code above does send the GET request to example.com (placeholder), but gets a response saying that it is not a valid query.

However, if I pass the str1 as follows -

```
var str1='<%=JSON.parse(HTTParty.get("http://example.com/api.php?param=xyz"))%>'
 $(".result").text(str1);
```

I get the expected response. If the $(".ajax-control") text field is "xyz", I get a response saying not a valid query.

Does string concatenation in javascript introduces new characters because of which it is throwing an error?

Answer (score 3):

That javascript (which in turn has ruby code via erb) is not going to execute after its been rendered the first time by Rails.

That is, its **not** going to be invoked each time that keypress callback is called, which means that when Rails is rendering that Javascript it obviously has no knowledge of the client-side DOM so the URL is affectively:

```
JSON.parse(HTTParty.get("http://example.com/api.php?param="))
```

And the remote server has an empty `param` which it doesnt like...

If you really need to invoke that API for every keypress you have two options:

1. Get it to work via Ajax using CORS
2. Invoke an endpoint in your Rails app,
   which in turn uses Ruby-side HTTParty to invoke the API and relay
   the response back to the client.

Comment: Thanks!  I finally understand why the problem occured. 
The reason why I was not using CORS was that the server from which hosts the API does not support it.

Is there any other way?

Comment: @ArjunBharadwaj if you cannot use CORS then your next best option is to use your own server to relay that HTTP request, so make a request to your server which invokes the example.com request and passes it back to your AJAX